# Google Tango: How is the point cloud confidence data can be used

Tags: java, google-project-tango, depth-buffer

I was working with the xyz data only till the updates of Tango API. I was wondering about the confidence data returned onPointCloudAvilable() callback, how can I benefit from this data?

are any point out of the range 0-1 is not a correct data? In another words, is it mean that if I eliminate points not in the range will give me more accurate point cloud depth data ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice:

I have tried to check the values of C for each frame I get, but the values are always 1.0. Someone knows if this is really implemented or it will in future releases?

In theory:

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/struct/tango-point-cloud):

```
An array of packed {X, Y, Z, C} values.
{X, Y, Z} is a coordinate triplet (in meters).  
C is a confidence value, in the range of [0, 1], 
where 1 corresponds to full confidence.
```

I haven't try yet but in theory all points are in the range [0,1]... being 1 the "best" points. So eliminating points lower than 0.5 (or 0.9) should reduce the noise of your acquisition.

Comment: Thank you @DanielGL for clarifying this. It really helpful :)

Comment: Yes, I also figure this while I'm checking on the results of the output cloud. I'm not using the last version of Tango java API, and also I'm not sure if this result is also applied for all Unity SDK and C API. I hope if someone can elaborate in this.